# filtering in stored procedure using oracle 11 g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which returns some data . I want to use a filter to get specific row

```
ID      NAME      SCHOOL

1      Jack       Highschool
2      Mike       Charter
3      Merry      University
4      Ahmet      Ph.D
```

I want to get only  jack and Ahmet by filtering ID .

How to achieve it ?

Thanks

Comment: You talk about a "specific row" but then talk about returning multiple rows.  What, exactly, do you want to return?  A `sys_refcursor`?  A `%rowtype`?  A collection?  Something else?

Comment: I have this table , I want to do select * from table where id='1' and '4'

Comment: Do you mean `IN`?  A row, obviously, cannot have both an `ID` of 1 and an `ID` of 4.  Are you saying that you want a stored procedure with an `OUT` parameter of type `sys_refcursor`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a table parameter to your stored procedure

```
CREATE TYPE paramTableType AS TABLE
(                     


   [ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,                

)
```

and fill a table with with this type with all IDs you want to filter with and then use a select statement like below one

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcedureName
(


  @TableVariable paramTableType  READONLY


)


AS  


BEGIN

select * from yourTable where ID IN (select * from @TableVariable )
END
```

I'm coming from a SQL back ground put try if works for Oracle .

1. List item